# footnotemark and footnotetext creates undesired indentation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, footnotes

I have looked for a solution for quite some time now, but I couldn't find anything useful. The problem seems to be minor but still visible.

If I use `footnotemark` within `align` to create a footnote, which is named via `footnotetext`, the following paragraph is slightly indented. This cannot be changed, even if I use `\noindent`.

Check the following simply example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
X_{t+1} &=  \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}  
\intertext{Some intertext...:\footnotemark} 
X_{t+1} &=  \frac{X_{t+1}+X_{t+1}}{Y_t}
\end{align*}
\footnotetext{English text is better understandable} 
\Blindtext[1][1]
\end{document}
```

There is a tiny horizontal space, before the blindtext starts. This seems to be added to any regular paragraph indentation as well - if you decide to make a new one after the align environment. Does anyone know how to handle this correctly?

Comment: End of line space!. Put a `%` after like `\footnotetext{English text is better understandable}%`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Ahh I KNEW it was something little like that. I never got to fully understand when to use `%` and when not to. People add these after some brackets and after others they don't. If you could add little more of an explanation I'd like to accept your answer! Edit: I also want to mention that I tried this but my editor (Tex Studio) didn't want to let me put the `%` easily at the end of the line, because it was exactly at the position of a linebreak :S

Comment: And BTW: You load `setspace` twice, one time is enough.

Comment: I have fixed that ;)

Comment: I had overread most of your answering comment to Harish. For the percent sign see [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HarishKumar pointed out, `%` was missing behind `\footnotetext{English text is better understandable}%`. He didn't make his comment an answer, but credit goes really to him (upvote his comment above if this answer was useful for you).